# Visual Studio 2015 Unable to Disable Browser Link

Tags: visual-studio-2015, browser-link

So just switched my project over to 2015 and a day or two later the browser link bar appeared at the top of browser.

I did my typical googling and found the setting in the toolbar and disabled it. That didn't work and it's still there.

[1st Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqBJZ.png)

Read about the second method of adding a few lines to the web.config. Also didn't work and it continues to plague me.

[2nd Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FplQ2.png)

Is there another method I should know about that can get rid of this thing. I saw the other method of disabling debug, which doesn't sound too appealing.